# Problem with signs in dcolumn package

Tags: multicolumn, dcolumn

I want to create a table with multicolumns where numbers are vertically aligned at the decimal sign, so I used the dcolumn package. Some of my numbers have negative signs.
For every second column my code perfectly works but not for the other columns. Can anybody figure out what I did wrong? Did I place the `D{.}{.}{-1}` commands at the right place?
My `\textwidth` commands seem to look a bit complicated but the table I posted here is just a small part of a very big multicolumn table where I need to specify the width of each column in order to get it fit to one page.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
{p{0.3\textwidth}
p{0.05\textwidth}D{.}{.}{-1}
p{0.05\textwidth}D{.}{.}{-1}
p{0.05\textwidth}D{.}{.}{-1}
p{0.05\textwidth}D{.}{.}{-1}
p{0.05\textwidth}D{.}{.}{-1}
p{0.05\textwidth}D{.}{.}{-1}
}

\addlinespace \toprule[0.5pt] \addlinespace

\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Position}}  &  \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Model1}}\\
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{82m Mast} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{SODAR 1}& \multicolumn{2}{l}{SODAR 2}  \\
& m/s & \% &  m/s & \% & m/s & \%   \\


\addlinespace \midrule \addlinespace

 Mast 1   & 0.0  & 0.0  & -0.3 & -7.4  & -0.3 & -8.4    \\
SODAR 1     & 0.4  & 7.8  & 0.0  & 0.0   & 0.1  & 1.3     \\
SODAR 2     & 0.3  & 7.8  & 0.0  & 0.0   & 0.0  & 0.0     \\
 Mast 2  & -0.1 & -2.5 & -0.4 & -10.8 & -0.5 &  -12.5   \\

\addlinespace \bottomrule[0.5pt] \addlinespace
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't understand quite well that a `D` column is … a column specifier. As is, your table has 13 columns. I suggest you remove the `\p{0.05\textwidth}` columns, and use the `X` type for the first one. You also should centre your `\multicolumn`s. Here is a code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\label{tab:troistorrents_differences}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}
{X
D{.}{.}{-1}
D{.}{.}{-1}
D{.}{.}{-1}
D{.}{.}{-1}
D{.}{.}{-1}
D{.}{.}{-1}
}
\toprule[0.5pt] 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Position}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Model 1}}\\
\addlinespace
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{82m Mast} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SODAR 1}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SODAR 2} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{m/s} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{m/s} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\%} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{m/s }& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\%} \\
\midrule
\addlinespace[0.75ex] 
 Mast 1 & 0.0 & 0.0 & -0.3 & -7.4 & -0.3 & -8.4 \\
SODAR 1 & 0.4 & 7.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.1 & 1.3 \\
SODAR 2 & 0.3 & 7.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
 Mast 2 & -0.1 & -2.5 & -0.4 & -10.8 & -0.5 & -12.5 \\
\bottomrule[0.5pt] 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your example works fine for me. My original table is much bigger than this example and I forgot to delete the additional comlumns in the header thats why there where 13..sorry. In my big 13 column table the Position column was always separated into two rows because the table was to big for one page. Thats why I used the `\p{0.12\textwidth}` command. I fixed that by reducing the space between columns with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` instead of controlling each column width separately.

Comment: I suppose the `p{0.12\textwdth}` was the leftmost column (`X` in my example)? Did you instead loading the `makecell` package, keeping the `X` qualifier, to achieve the exact text width for the table, while the `\makecell` command allows for line breaks inside cells and a common formatting (vertical and horizontal formatting, font, &c.).

Comment: I would remove the `\addlinespace` instructions around `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`.

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I didn't notice these details from the O.P.'s code. I kept one (smaller) `\addlinespace`, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `siunitx` that allows easier fine tuning

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=-1.1]
 S[table-format=-1.1]
 S[table-format=-1.1]
 S[table-format=-2.1]
 S[table-format=-1.1]
 S[table-format=-2.1]
}
\toprule
\textbf{Position} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Model1}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-7}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\SI{82}{m} Mast}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SODAR 1}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{SODAR 2}  \\
& {\si{m/s}} & {\%} & {\si{m/s}} & {\%} & {\si{m/s}} & {\%} \\
\midrule
Mast 1  &  0.0 &  0.0 & -0.3 &  -7.4 & -0.3 &  -8.4 \\
SODAR 1 &  0.4 &  7.8 &  0.0 &   0.0 &  0.1 &   1.3 \\
SODAR 2 &  0.3 &  7.8 &  0.0 &   0.0 &  0.0 &   0.0 \\
Mast 2  & -0.1 & -2.5 & -0.4 & -10.8 & -0.5 & -12.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]